# How to set a fixed header while using LazyColumn?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I'm trying to have a little icon at the top of a LazyColumn that scrolls like any other item in the list.  My googling has yielded no luck and I'm wondering if it's even possible yet.  Looking for a resource that could help me implement this.  To be clear I know stickyHeader exists and that's not what I'm looking for since it  will stay at the top of the screen and not scroll with the items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add another item in the body of the `LazyColumn` if it's just like any other row and you want it to scroll.

```
LazyColumn {
   item {
      Icon()
   }

   items(myItemList) {
   
   }
}
```

Comment: can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73531243/11560810)

Comment: in newer versions, there is also `stickyHeader {
        }`

Comment: `stickyHeader` is the one I'm looking for, thanks for this!